# How to export InteliJ project to an executable with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jar

I have created a project within InteliJ with a simple GUI Form, everything works normally when I attempt to run it and debug it.

Now I wanted to actually make it into an executable. (complete noob btw)

I have read numerous articles from Stackoverflow, on how to make a executable JAR file, and previously when I was testing the program without a GUI everything worked normally.

I had extracted it to a JAR file, made a simple console launcher and everything was working normally.

Nevertheless, now when I do the same process with the gui, and execute the launcher or click on the jar file itself, it does nothing.

Within my Main Class, all I do is simply call the GUI and from there everything else is within the listeners and so forth:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();


    }
}
```

Was hoping to get a JAR file, that once you open it, the simple GUI shows up and you can use the program.

Comment: by buillding it. "it does nothing" is most likely "it tries to do a lot, but the resources that were on the path of my ide are not on my classpath"

Comment: Run it on the command line to see if exceptions are being thrown

Comment: @Stultuske Nope. Building it creates class files, not jar files.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus looks like your building process differs from mine.

Comment: If you see exceptions when following the advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels, try to solve them. If you cannot, prepare a [mre] and [edit] the question to add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple project (no build environment like Maven), you manually create an 'artifact' which is a fully-customizable description of how to export your project when you execute 'build artifact'. You can have multiple artifacts, but for a simple project, an artifact that just puts the 'compile output' in a 'jar' is sufficient.

Go to <kbd>Project structure</kbd>→<kbd>Artifacts</kbd>, click the <kbd>+ (Add)</kbd> button,→<kbd>JAR</kbd>→<kbd>From module with dependencies...</kbd>

Specify the main class and voilà. The artifact (description of how to export) is created.

To 'build the artifact' to actually get the jar file, go to menu <kbd>Build</kbd>→<kbd>Build artifacts...</kbd>, click the name of the artifact.

Watch the status bar for the 'Build completed successfully' message.

For more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

I was not selecting the main, that is the reason why it was not working.